# iOS8 - UILocalNotification, Check for permission later from code

Tags: swift, ios8, uilocalnotification

I am writing my application in Swift for iOS8.

I wanted to use UILocalNotification to notify user of some things. For that, I have asked permission at the app launch with this:

```
application.registerUserNotificationSettings(UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: UIUserNotificationType.Sound | UIUserNotificationType.Alert | UIUserNotificationType.Badge, categories: nil))
```

A confirm box shows up asking for permission. If user allows it, there's no problem.

If the user does not give permission, how do I check if local notifications are enabled from code (programmatically)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/currentUserNotificationSettings)

```
application.currentUserNotificationSettings()
```

Answer (score 8):

..and this is how you check it in Swift:

```
let currentSettings = UIApplication.sharedApplication().currentUserNotificationSettings()
let required:UIUserNotificationType = UIUserNotificationType.Sound; // Add other permissions as required
let notification = UILocalNotification()

    if (currentSettings.types & required) != nil {
        println("sound will come and also vibration")
        notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName
    }else{
        println("no sound no vibration")
    }
```

**Nice to know:
 
it will vibrate automatically, whether sound is on/off over your iphone button - nothing will happen if the user will set sound off in settings for your app.
 So you don't have to add vibration additionally.**

Comment: Where does `notification.soundName` come from? Without that, this works. Thanks.

Comment: @MKatleast3 - oh thank you, I've just forgot to add a UILocalNotification variable. In my function its lots of more lines - I recommend you to configurate your notification exactly. the "if" box is very important for my solution.

Comment: Nice, thx ! With Swift 3, consider using --- if (currentSettings?.types.contains(required))! --- instead of & operator which is now deprecated between 2 UIUserNotificationType members

Answer (score 4):

For the record, this is how you check the permissions in Objective-C:

```
UIUserNotificationSettings *current = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] currentUserNotificationSettings];
UIUserNotificationSettings *required = UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert; // Add other permissions as required
if(current.types & required) {
    NSLog(@"Permission present: 0x%ulX", settings.types);
} else {
    NSLog(@"Permission not present: 0x%ulX", settings.types);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/registerUserNotificationSettings:) answers you question like this:

> After calling this method, the app calls the application:didRegisterUserNotificationSettings: method of its app delegate to report the results. You can use that method to determine if your request was granted or denied by the user.